# Inline Assembler and Bitfield access

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, inline-assembly

I want to set the following bit field in inline assembler.

```
EVSYS->Channel[2].CHINTFLAG.bit.EVD = 1
```

The struct is:

```
typedef union { 
  struct {
    uint8_t  OVR:1; 
    uint8_t  EVD:1;
    uint8_t  :6;
  } bit;  uint8_t reg; 
} EVSYS_CHINTFLAG_Type;
```

It works with the following:

```
#define VUSB_RESET_IRQ() \
            asm volatile(  \
                "mov r5, %[value9]\n\t" \
                "orr r5,r5,#0x40\n\t" \
                "strb r5, [%[addr9]]"  \
            : : [value9] "r"(EVSYS->Channel[2].CHINTFLAG.reg), \
                    [addr9] "r"(&(EVSYS->Channel[2].CHINTFLAG.reg))  \
            : "r5", "memory");
```

But can this be done better in assembler because the gcc O3 with .EVD is:

```
   156:     EVSYS->Channel[2].CHINTFLAG.bit.EVD = 1;
200002CA   ldr  r2, [pc, #28]        
200002CC   ldrb.w   r3, [r2, #54]        
200002D0   orr  r3, r3, #2       
200002D4   strb.w   r3, [r2, #54]
```

My handwritten inline is:

```
155:    VUSB_RESET_IRQ();
200002CC   ldr  r3, [pc, #44]        
200002CE   ldr  r1, [pc, #48]        
200002D0   ldrb.w   r2, [r3, #54]        
200002D4   mov  r5, r2       
200002D6   orr  r5, r5, #64      
200002DA   strb r5, [r1]
```

---

EDIT:
I changed the code to this and it compiles to the desired asm:

```
#define VUSB_RESET_IRQ() \
                asm volatile( \
                    "orr %[out], %[value],#1<<1\n\t" \
                :   [out] "=r"(EVSYS_CHANNEL_CHINTFLAG_2)  \
                : [value] "r"(EVSYS_CHANNEL_CHINTFLAG_2) \
                : "memory");
```

Comment: Your problem is including a useless `mov` inside the asm template, and hard-coding the addressing mode for an `strb`.  Just use a `+r` operand and `orr %[value9], #0x40`.  Also, get your immediate right: the 2nd bit is `#1<<1`, not `#1<<6`.  ARM bitfields are ordered from lowest to highest bit.

Comment: The C code has some serious problems as you have demonstrated, but if your goal was to set bit 6 then technically you did that.  As pointed out with an extra, unnecessary instruction as well as using r5 which is a register your function needs to preserve, you have not shown all the code, so we can only help so much.

Comment: If you have a separate question about your hand-written asm interrupt handler not working, post that separately.  The reasons could be not setting the interrupt handler correctly, or IDK what else.  But it's definitely a separate question, unrelated to the title question of bitfield access from inline asm.  People that get here from a search engine will be looking for an answer to that.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is including a useless `mov` inside the asm template, and hard-coding the addressing mode for an `strb`.  That forces GCC to materialize a pointer into a register, and for some reason it chooses not to use that for an ldrb before the asm.  The `mov` inside your asm template is pure waste: you're already asking for the value in a register.

Just use a `"+r"(value9)` operand and `orr %[value9], #0x2`.  Don't hard-code any registers if you don't need to, so you can avoid any clobbers.

Or use a separate `"=r"(EVSYS->Channel[2].CHINTFLAG.reg)` output to give the compiler the option of using an `orr` with a separate destination so the original value is also still around in a register.

(And get your immediate right: the 2nd bit is `#1<<1`, not `#1<<6`.  ARM bitfields are ordered from lowest to highest bit, as we can see from the GCC output)

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for more about writing inline asm that doesn't suck.

---

### Or better, don't use inline asm for this at all

**https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**

As you already demonstrated, GCC makes efficient asm already so there's zero benefit.  And in fact the net benefit is negative: even with efficient inline asm, you'd still be defeating optimizations like constant-propagation and CSE.  (Use a cast to `volatile*` if/when you *need* to defeat those optimizations, not `asm volatile`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Our function is a RAM function and this function are called from the Interrupt vector table. The problem is that if you optimize the code the result is not always what you want. Therefore we must write code which is not optimized (rearranged) inside a function. Also we can not call other functions because of the time restrictions.

Comment: @makurisan: Like I said, use `volatile EVSYS_CHINTFLAG_Type*` if/when you need to stop optimization, or `_Atomic`.  If you're writing in C at all, you should be able to use pure C.  If you can't use C, then write in pure asm.  It's very rare that *inline* asm is helpful.

Comment: @makurisan  If the code “breaks” when being optimised, it is incorrect.  This is a typical symptom of not understanding what counts as a visible side effect as far as C is concerned and can be addressed with appropriate usage of `volatile`.  Inline assembly does not solve this problem and only makes your code a lot more complex for no good reason.  Please reconsider your approach if possible.